# Adding index to numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `numpy` array as:

```
prob_rf = [[0.4, 0.4, 0.4], 
           [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
           [0.6, 0.6, 0.6]]
```

I want to add an index number to each of the inner arrays as:

```
prob_rf = [[1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4],
           [2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
           [3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6]]
```

and then save this array into a `csv` file using `numpy.savetxt`.

I am currently doing this as:

```
    id = [i for i in xrange(1,len(prob)+1)]
    prob_rf = np.insert(prob_rf, 0, id, axis=1)
    np.savetxt("foo.csv", prob_rf, delimiter=",", fmt='%1.1f')
```

But this is giving the output as

```
[[1.0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4], 
 [2.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
 [3.0, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6]]
```

Could someone please tell me how do I get the output as

```
[[1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4], 
 [2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
 [3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6]]
```

Comment: Why are you telling numpy to format everything with `fmt='%1.1f'` if that's not what you want?

Comment: It's because I want them in the format `[0.4, 0.4, 0.4]` else np.savetext saves as `[4.00E-01, 4.00E-01, 4.00E-01]` which I don't want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a list with the `fmt` parameter to specify the formatting for each column:

```
fmt=['%d', '%1.1f', '%1.1f', '%1.1f']
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
prob_rf = [[1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4],
           [2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
           [3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6]]
np.savetxt("foo.csv", prob_rf, delimiter=",", fmt=['%d', '%1.1f', '%1.1f', '%1.1f'])
```

The resulting file:

```
1,0.4,0.4,0.4
2,0.5,0.5,0.5
3,0.6,0.6,0.6
```